# Make a new variable/column in a data frame with a certain quality from an existing data frame

Tags: r

I am new to this site so sorry if this post is crappy.

I am working from a massive data file, so I will give a small example of what it looks like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kJ1R.png).

In this data file, the "plate" column has three values: 1,2, and 3. I am attempting to make three new columns, with each column having the "Abs.530nm" value for the specific row if it contains the corresponding plate number (ex separate the absorbance values from plate 1 into a new column, etc)

this is what I attempted to do:

```
data.row$plate %<>% factor(levels = c("1","2","3"))

data.row %>%
 group_by(box, plate) %>%
 diff.tr.1.2 <- subset(plate, name.start <-"1", drop=FALSE) %>%


{.} ->data.tech
```

I got this error:

```
Error in subset(plate, name.start <- "1", drop = FALSE) : 
object 'plate' not found
```

Is there a way to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: You are using `base R` syntax along with `dplyr`.  I think you need `data.row %>% group_by(box, plate = factor(plate, levels = 1:3)) %>% filter(name.start ==1)` the `subset` part is not clear.  Did you meant `name.start == 1`

Answer (score 0):

The `data.table` package is very fast for large data sets, and it's very easy to subset like you describe.

I suggest rather than creating three separate Abs.530nm columns, that you simply filter the data frame three different ways, one for each factor level. That's a much cleaner solution than introducing NA values in a "ABS.530nm Plate 1" column

Assuming your data frame is called `df`

```
require(data.table)
as.data.table(df)

#  plate == 1 is your "filter" selecting only rows where the plate is 1
#  by defines your grouping, in this case, by box, then by plate

output <- df[plate ==1, by= .(box,plate)]
```